# Trouble with selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium

I have a trouble with selenium/ python.

```
<th scope="row"><span class="nowrap">Lieu de naissance</span>
</th>

<a href="/fr/Comt%C3%A9_de_Westmoreland_(Virginie)" title="Comté de Westmoreland (Virginie)" class="int-link">Comté de Westmoreland</a>
```

every time I see "Lieu de naissance", I would like to take the element after (the following one)

I tried :

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Lieu de naissance')]/descendant::td[last()]")

this is the website.
https://www.wikiwand.com/fr/George_Washington

thanks a lot

Comment: We see no selenium / python code here

Comment: its html but i use selenium/python to select it

Comment: Can you provide a link to the web page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tried to mix `xpath` and `css` syntaxes.
You can use the following `xpat` locator for that element:
`//td//a[contains(@href,'Westmoreland')]`

If you need this to be with dependence of `<span class="nowrap">Lieu de naissance</span>` element  you can use `//span[contains(text(),'Lieu de naissance')]/../..//a` or `(//span[contains(text(),'Lieu de naissance')]/../..//a)[1]`

Comment: I cant do that because i want to select all the presidents of USA and of course the birthplace (Lieu de naissance) is going to change.

Comment: OK, changes per that element dependence

Comment: Sure. You have to put `"` (double quotes) before the entire `xpath` expression if you are using single quotes `'` for the element text or vise versa i.e. single quotes before and after the entire expression and double quotes for the element text